# How does the expression in ng-repeat work?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-factory

I'm trying to figure out how to loop through an array of objects, with ng-repeat.

I've got a factory set up like this, with three sets data in it:

```js
mainApp.factory("dashboardContent", function() {
    return {
        contentBoxes: [
            {
                boxType: "image",
                boxIcon: "icons-image",
                boxTitle: "on Chapter 1, paragraph 3",
                header: {
                    title: "Lorem ipsum title sit amet",
                    subtitle: "by Lorem Ipsum"
                },
                authorImage: "/asssets/ssfsgterwes",
                embedContent: ""
            },
            {
                boxType: "audio",
                boxIcon: "icons-audio",
                boxTitle: "on Chapter 12, paragraph 2",
                header: {
                    title: "lorem ipsum audio sit maet",
                    subtitle: "by multiple objects"
                },
                authorImage: "/asssets/ssfsgterwes",
                embedContent: ""
            },
            {
                boxType: "quote",
                boxIcon: "icons-lightbulb",
                boxTitle: "on Chapter 01, paragraph 5",
                header: {
                    title: "lorem ipsum quote sit maet",
                    subtitle: "by multiple objects parsing"
                },
                authorImage: "/asssets/ssfsgterwes",
                embedContent: ""
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

And a directive where I've injected the factory:

```js
.directive('contentBox', function(dashboardContent) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/modules/contentbox.html',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.contentData = dashboardContent.contentBoxes;
            if (!$.isEmptyObject(scope.contentData.header)) {
                element.children('.content').prepend(
                    '<div class="content-header">' +
                        '<span class="content-title">' +
                            scope.contentData.header.title +
                        '</span>' +
                    '   <br/>' +
                    '</div>'
                );
                if (!$.isEmptyObject(scope.contentData.header.subtitle)) {
                    element.find('.content-header').append(
                        '<span class="content-author">' +
                            scope.contentData.header.subtitle +
                        '</span>'
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

In my view, I'm trying to loop through it like this:

```xml
<content-box ng-repeat="content in contentData"></content-box>
```

What's the expression I'd need to use in this case? I can't understand from the [ng-repeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat#) docs how this expression works, I've figured out that in "content in contentData", contentData is referring to my set of of objects, but what is the first word (content, as I set it here), what does it refer to?

Also, did I set up this scope correctly? Like in the code above:

```js
scope.contentData = dashboardContent.contentBoxes;
```

The output that I'm getting from this are three empty content boxes, so I'm guessing it's looping through it, but no data is being printed in them - i.e. {{contentData.boxTitle}} just returns empty

Am I using ng-repeat correctly in this situation ?

Comment: You are using ng-repeat correctly, I'm not sure but I think for repetative operations like this you should use `compile` rather than `link` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are injecting your service `dashboardContent` directly into your directive. It's not necessary. Insted you could inject it into your controller, access single array elements with `ng-repeat` and pass those to your directive.

```
mainApp.controller('ContentCtrl', function($scope, dashboardContent) { 
  $scope.contentData = dashboardContent.contentBoxes;
});
```

In your directive code replace

```
scope: {}
```

with

```
scope: { contentData: '='}
```

and remove line `scope.contentData=...`

This way you'll have a directive with isolate scope and you can pass a value to this scope in your html like this:

```
<div ng-controller="ContentCtrl" ng-repeat="content in contentBoxes">
  <content-box contentData="content"></content-box>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, you've given me a great insight towards angular's functioning logic.

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution to my specific issue has be detailed by [Esa Toivola in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17485516/739723), but I wanted to mention how angular ng-repeat works, as per my original question.

In the syntax:

```
<div ng-repeat="content in contentData"></div>
```

In this situation:

**contentData** - the actual array/data you're using

**content** - the object you are *binding*

So further on you'd continue as:

```
<div ng-repeat="content in contentData">
    {{content.title}}
</div>
```

Where content is the object you're outputting and title is one of it's parameters.